# Neo4j on Microsoft Azure Deployment template validation failed?

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-virtual-machine

**EDITED**
*My azure subscription is Visual Studio Enterprise:* ***BizSpark***

When trying to configure neo4j on Microsoft Azure by following the guide explained on [How to Deploy Neo4j on Microsoft Azure Step-by-Step](https://neo4j.com/blog/deploy-neo4j-microsoft-azure-part-2/)

On Step 2: Neo4j Settings... there is no SSL certificate options, VM options as explained on the guide

[image]

after clicking **OK**..... the following error showed up, stating

```
    InvalidTemplate
Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'SubnetName' at line '56' and column '20' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.
```

[image]

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to be Azure platform issue. Works now!

Comment: For now, we can deploy neo4j via Azure portal now, please test it with Azure portal.  Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: It works like a charm now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I create neo4j from Azure marketplace, get the same error as you. I can't download this template and check it.

As a work around, we can follow this [template](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/neo4j.neo4j-enterprise-edition?tab=Overview) to create neo4j cluster.
[image]

After select continue, we will login Azure portal with your Azure Account, then we can use this template to create neo4j:
[image]

Here is the **result**:
[image]

===================================================
**Update**:

It seems Azure fix this problem, we can deploy it via Azure portal now.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: For now, we can deploy neo4j via Azure portal, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the thing is broken, nothing you can do about it (I've followed the link you gave filled out the forms and got the same error). Contact people who created it (Neo Technology, Inc) and tell them about this problem.

They have a [public slack](http://neo4j-users-slack-invite.herokuapp.com).

Few things to look around thou:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/lap-neo4j-ubuntu
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/docker-neo4j

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there has been some issues with Azure displaying the configuration settings - I've just gone through and see this:

[image]

Which is what you should see. The template is asking for a 'Subnet' to be set, but the Azure UI wasn't letting you - you should find it's working now.

As to why - well - it could be MS noticed and fixed something - Azure was just having a moment - but let's just go with  **MAGIC** as that's as good-a-guess as any other.

Comment: As an update. Microsoft confirmed that it was an Azure issue, and it is now properly resolved.