# Access Neo4j server with Ubuntu OS over the Internet(Public IP address)?

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-virtual-network

My Neo4j version is 3.2.2 Enterprise edition. The server I am using is VM Ubuntu 16.0 Server on Microsoft Azure. I want to access it over the public address. For the time being I turned off the firewall on Ubuntu. I also configured, Neo4j network configuration which is found on **/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf** to be accessible outside the local network.

The problem is, I am unable to access it with public IP address. Keeps saying time is out.

I tried to use Neo4j enterprise template on Microsoft Azure but the following error which is posted on this link [Neo4j on Microsoft Azure Deployment template validation failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057862/neo4j-on-microsoft-azure-deployment-template-validation-failed) keeps showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access neo4j from your Azure VM?

According to your description, it seems a NSG settings issue.

As we know, those ports should be opened up in our **firewall settings** and **Azure NSG settings**:

[image]
It seems you have turn off your ubuntu firewall, so we just add those ports to Azure NSG inbound rules, like this:

[image]

We can add NSG inbound rules **via Azure portal**, more information about set NSG inbound rules, please refer to this link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal

By the way, we can use this [template](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/neo4j.neo4j-enterprise-edition?tab=Overview) to deploy neo4j cluster in Azure, more information about it, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057862/neo4j-on-microsoft-azure-deployment-template-validation-failed/45227709#45227709).

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: For now, we can via Azure portal to deploy neo4j, please check the answer in this linkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057862/neo4j-on-microsoft-azure-deployment-template-validation-failed/45227709#45227709   thanks:)